# JPA bidirectional relations: structure in Database

Tags: jpa, glassfish, java-ee-6

I'm starting using JPA in Netbeans with a Glassfish server + Derby Database, and I have some doubts on its behavior. I did the following experiment: I defined an entity "User" with the property

```
@OneToMany(cascade=ALL, mappedBy="user")
    public List<Thing> getThings() {
    return things;
}
```

and the entity "Thing" with the property

```
@ManyToOne
public Cook4User getUser() {
    return user;
}
```

Then I persisted one user and added one "Thing" to it. Everything all right, I can see the two tables "User" and "Thing" with one entry each, with the second table having a foreign key indicating the user id. 
Then I removed the element from the "Thing" table, ran a select statement to recover the user, called the getThings() method on it and... I still found the element that I had removed from the Thing table! How is it possible? Where is it stored? I can't see it nowhere in the DB! Thanks for clearing things up to me.

EDIT: I tried to isolate the lines of code that produce the issue.

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

User user = new User();
em.persist(user);
Thing thing = new Thing();
em.persist(thing);
user.getThings().add(thing);
em.remove(thing);
user = em.find(User.class, userid);
logger.log(Level.INFO, "user still contains {0} things", user.getThings().size());
\\thing is still there!
```

Comment: When you say '_Then I removed the element from the "Thing" table_', did you remove the record from the actual database with a SQL query like `delete from Thing...` or via JPA?

Comment: I did it with JPA. As usual, I called the EntityManager from PersistenceContext in my EJB, looked up for the element in the Thing table then removed it with the remove() method. Then I checked the DB through a select statement in Netbeans and the Thing table was actually empty.

Comment: Difficult to help without the code. Would you mind adding the relevant  snippets of code that reproduce this problem?

Comment: I added some code, let me know if you need more. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In the form of a JUnit test with SpringRunner and Hibernate as the JPA implementation:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:spring-context.xml")
public class TestThings {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestThings.class);

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void does_not_remove_thing() {
        Cook4User user = new Cook4User();
        em.persist(user);

        Thing thing = new Thing();
        em.persist(thing);
        user.getThings().add(thing);

        user = em.find(Cook4User.class, user.getId());
        user.getThings().forEach((t) -> log.info("1 >> Users thing: {}", t.getId()));

        em.remove(thing);
        em.flush();

        user = em.find(Cook4User.class, user.getId());
        user.getThings().forEach((t) -> log.info("2 >> Users thing: {}", t.getId()));

        assertThat(user.getThings()).isEmpty();
    }

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void removes_thing_when_removed_from_owning_side() {
        Cook4User user = new Cook4User();
        em.persist(user);

        Thing thing = new Thing();
        em.persist(thing);
        user.getThings().add(thing);

        user = em.find(Cook4User.class, user.getId());
        user.getThings().forEach((t) -> log.info("1 >> Users thing: {}", t.getId()));

        user.getThings().remove(thing);

        user = em.find(Cook4User.class, user.getId());
        user.getThings().forEach((t) -> log.info("2 >> Users thing: {}", t.getId()));

        assertThat(user.getThings()).isEmpty();
    }
}
```

The first test `does_not_remove_thing` is per your question and fails as you have experienced, this is the output of that test with `hibernate.show_sql` logging set to true:

```
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        Cook4User
        (id) 
    values
        (null)
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        Thing
        (id, user_id) 
    values
        (null, ?)
[main] INFO  TestThings - 1 >> Users thing: 1
[main] INFO  TestThings - 2 >> Users thing: 1
java.lang.AssertionError: expecting empty but was:<[x.Thing@276]>
```

The second test `removes_thing_when_removed_from_owning_side` passes with output:

```
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        Cook4User
        (id) 
    values
        (null)
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        Thing
        (id, user_id) 
    values
        (null, ?)
[main] INFO  TestThings - 1 >> Users thing: 1
```

So it looks like removing your `Thing` from the owning side of the relationship (he he) is the way to go.

Although, I must be honest, I'm not sure why exactly that works and your way does not. I would understand if you removed your `Thing` from a detached entity but that was not the case. Also, I was expecting a `delete` query after calling `em.remove(thing)` for `Thing` somewhere but nothing (I added `em.flush()` to try force that).

Maybe someone else can shed some light on the finer mechanics of what's going on here?

Comment: thanks for the answer, this remains quite a mistery to me... and apparently not so many people are using JPA!